# Resistance band chest press

Tags: bodybuilding, chest

I am trying out resistance band workouts. I am fairly experienced using barbells and dumbbells. While trying chest press using a band, I feel my triceps more than my chest. What could be possibly wrong?
Any good YouTube videos on resistance band workouts?

Comment: Resistance bands do not provide the same resistance as weights (the  bands increase their resistance as they are pulled ), so you wuold feel the weight in a slightly different way.

Comment: Liiuc is correct. Bands provide the greatest resistance towards the end of the movement, where your triceps are doing almost all of the work.

Comment: Yeah I get that part. But to feel triceps is normal or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. It's what you would expect with a band chest press.